# Convert System Date to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: batch-file

Before i raise my query let me tell I am new to Batch files..

I have a requirement where in i want to convert the system Date to DD/MM/YYYY format, can someone please help me out?

Comment: I have tried below code :               FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B 
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B 
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B         If my system date is  02/21/2013 i am getting output as 21 /02 /2013. A extra space is coming after Date and month

Comment: Perhaps in each case the space is after `%%B` in the `SET` statements. Use double quotes like this: `SET "mm=%%B"`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdfuncs/dandt/index.html#getdate

```
@echo off
call :GetDate year month day
echo/Today is: %day%-%month%-%year%
goto :EOF

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:GetDate yy mm dd
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-06-15. Version 1.0
::
:: Func: Loads local system date components into args 1 to 3. For NT4/2K/XP
::
:: Args: %1 var to receive year, 4 digits (by ref)
::       %2 var to receive month, 2 digits, 01 to 12 (by ref)
::       %3 Var to receive day of month, 2 digits, 01 to 31 (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set t=2&if "%date%z" LSS "A" set t=1
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('echo/^|date') do (
  for /f "tokens=%t%-4 delims=.-/ " %%d in ('date/t') do (
    set %%a=%%d&set %%b=%%e&set %%c=%%f))
endlocal&set %1=%yy%&set %2=%mm%&set %3=%dd%&goto :EOF
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```